# How are route metric values calculated in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I was wondering how the metric of a route is calculated by Linux. For example, the host routing table in my Ubuntu 16.04 has two routes and each is assigned a metric of 100.

Are there any dynamic formulas to calculate the metric based on the speed of the interface, characteristics, etc. or a fixed table is used?

[image]

Also can anyone refer me to the Linux source code that is responsible for metric calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I can't point you to the source code, but the route table is interpreted thus:

More specific routes - ie those with a more specific netmask (Genmask) - get priority over those with a higher netmask.

If you have 2 entries for the same route with the same netmask, the lower number is seen as a shorter distance and traffic will be sent out that.

Within the standard routing table there are no dynamic formulas to calculate the metric based on the speed of the interface, its just a table - but you can modify this metric.  (In ubuntu, /etc/interfaces will allow you to specify an option metric with a given metric, likewise things like OpenVPN will allow you to specify route metrics for given routes).  A metric of 100 seems to be the default.

Note that you can have multiple routing tables set up differently and do source routing.  Similar logic applies, and I don't believe delving into this is within the scope of the question.